# Page moves to top on postback of control in updatepanel

Tags: .net, ajax

I have an update panel on my page and anytime I have a control postback in it, the page scrolls back up to the top of the page.

Why would this happen?  How can I fix this?

Comment: I am having this same problem, and MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack doesn't fix it.  The focus is where it should be; the page scrolls up as high as it can while still keeping the focused control visible.  It affects Chrome and Firefox, but not IE.  I do not have this problem when I use my own client-side Ajaxery -- only with UpdatePanel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used control.focus() on the server side to fixed this issue.  For example:

```
Protected Sub ddlGroups_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlGroups.SelectedIndexChanged

        LoadGroups()

        ddlGroups.Focus()

 End Sub
```

I don't know if this is the best way but it works for me right now.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question has already been answered, but I think I have a simpler solution.  I needed a client side solution and this worked just fine.

What was happening to me was that I loaded a page and then lazy-loaded a Panel after the main page had loaded completely.  If I scrolled down my main page at all then when the Panel finished loading, my whole page would just scroll to the top.  So this code keeps track of any scrolling that I might be doing while my Panel is loading.  Then once the Panel has finished loading, instead of scrolling to the top, the page just scrolls to exactly where I just was.  So far this works fine in IE, Chrome, FF, Opera and Safari

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var yPos;
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();    
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
    $(window).scroll(function () { yPos = $(window).scrollTop(); });
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {        
        $(window).scrollTop(yPos);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the [MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback.aspx) on the page.

Edit:  Hmmm, okay ... [is this similar to the issue you are seeing?](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=103014&wa=wsignin1.0)

Comment: I have that MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack set to true and I'm still having the problem.

Comment: <%@ Page Language="vb" EnableEventValidation="false" AutoEventWireup="false" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" enableviewstate="true" Codefile="xxx.aspx.vb" Inherits="xxx" %>

Comment: No, it is not the scroll position in the panel it is the scroll positon of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Please try PageRequestManager handlers

```
<script>
              Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);



        function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
            try {

                sender._controlIDToFocus = null;


            }
            catch (e) {
            }
        }

</script>
```