# Asp.net Page moves down after load

Tags: asp.net

I've noticed that after using `<asp:panel>` or `<asp:UpdatePanel>` my page is jumping/scrolling down after the page has finished rendering. Also after a asynchronous post back, the page moves to the same place instead of staying right where it is. I don't have any focus set in the code behind of my page.

It's probably worth mentioning that on page load I am updating some asp.net controls within the `<asp:UpdatePanel>`. Mostly database driven dropdowns.

I'm wondering if anyone knows of any reason why a page would jump down. Is there some default focus or something that happens to certain asp.net controls?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Things I've Tried:

[How to keep whole page scroll position after asynchronous postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948417/how-to-keep-whole-page-scroll-position-after-asynchronous-postback)

Update1: 
I've used **David Stratton** script to get the correct position. However the page still jumps down then jumps back to the correct position. My goal is to have the page not jump at all.

This is the mark-up of my page, there are control between these.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel9" runat="server">

    <asp:Panel ID="tagpanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnAddTag">
    </asp:Panel>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel5" runat="server">

    <asp:Panel ID="pnlIncidentInfo" runat="server">
    </asp:Panel>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

***Note*** The issue described here is ***NOT*** related to the MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback.  I've had this issue myself and it's related to the UpdatePanel control.

From 
http://weblogs.asp.net/andrewfrederick/archive/2008/03/04/maintain-scroll-position-after-asynchronous-postback.aspx

First, set up a div just inside the ContentTemplate named "scrollDiv".

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
       <div id="scrollDiv">
          The rest of your page content goes here.
       </div>
     </ContentTemplate>
  <asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and then the JavaScript, as the article says, goes after the ScriptManager on your page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var xPos, yPos;
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        xPos = $get('scrollDiv').scrollLeft;
        yPos = $get('scrollDiv').scrollTop;
    }
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        $get('scrollDiv').scrollLeft = xPos;
        $get('scrollDiv').scrollTop = yPos;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Ah ! I think this is the trick!.  Deleting my answer regarding the MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback.

Comment: I've tried the above javascript after my ScriptManager however the page shows the correct position when its loading. when it's done it looks like the page goes to the middle.

Comment: @DavidStratton: Ah ! My one comment wasted !! :)

Comment: Found a better script, updated the answer.  Please let me know if it works!

Comment: After adding the new *edited* javascript, I think it needs a div tag called `scrollDiv` however Im not sure if it should surround my entire page or just be a container like `<div id="scrollDiv"></div>`. I've tried both ways to no success sorry. This is a tough one for me.

Comment: Looking at the script, it LOOKS like it should be just inside the ContentTemplate tag.  Editing the answer above...

Comment: Hi David, This script does in fact work now. However my page is jumping down, then jumping up to the correct place. I don't want it to jump at all. Thank you for your continued help with this. It's greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're using [MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback.aspx)?

Comment: I do have that in my page deceleration. removing it or leaving it there makes no difference